# Filter a find by the last element on an embedded array

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB how can I do a search that is filtered by a predicate applied on the last element of an embedded array?

I know if I wanted to do it on the first one I could do this:

```
db.inventory.find( { 'instock.0.qty': { $lte: 20 } } )
```

As specified on the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

How do I write an analog query that looks at the last element, when I don't know the exact size of the embedded array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use `$arrayElemAt` and pass -1 to it as a second argument to get the last element in the array

something like this

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$instock.qty", -1]
      },
      10
    ]
  }
})
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q6BYHJsjuE2)

hope it helps